# Ошибки в кодировках (плагин для chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Приветствую. Пишу плагин для Google Chrome, когда изменяю содержимое popup-а плагина через JS - кириллица отображается неправильно, пробовал менять charset в HTML popup-а - не помогает. Как это можно победить? Спасибо.

Comment: Используй utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего JS-скрипт, которым вы изменяете содержимое (полагаю подставляете новое значение) имеет отличную от popup-страницы кодировку.